# Getting Profile ID of User from his Jobs using Sessions and LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, session

As the title says. I have a page with a Job that have an ID. This ID I am storing in a Session and when I am trying to access the Company profile I just test if the Session Variable with Job ID from the tables Jobs and then I am trying to select the User ID and then with this User ID I search in UserManager and try to populate the page with some data.

Code For Company Profile:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Details(string id)
    {
        String JobValID = Convert.ToString(Session["DetailsURL"]);

        var UserJobID = context.Jobs.Where(x => x.ID.ToString() == JobValID).OrderByDescending(x => x.UserID).Select(x => x).ToString();
        UserJobID = id; //This line is to see what value I got from LINQ and is still the Session value.

        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        return View(user);

      }
```

View For this Controller is default scaffolded View from controller.

And like This I get `Session["DetailsURL"]`

```
var currentID = Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"];          
Session["DetailsURL"] = currentID;
```

I guess this is not the standard way to get a User Profile page. But I am using an `ActionLink` from Job Page to get into the Company Profile.

Here `ActionLink` to get from JobPage to Company Profile:

```
@Html.ActionLink("About this company", "Details", "UserAdmin", new { id = Session["UserJobID"] }, null)
```

My problem is in `LINQ` statement, when I am trying to select UserID, it doesn't get the right value, and when I am searching in UserManager the value is still the `session` Value.

[Found the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015081/c-sharp-linq-how-to-retrieve-a-single-result)
So how I did it:

```
    var UserJobId = (from c in context.Jobs
                     where c.ID == JobValID
                     select new { c.UserID }).Single();

    var myVal = UserJobId.UserID;
    id = myVal;
```

Comment: Your linq statement is confusing me. Why are you calling `ToString()` on a collection ? also what is the use of `Select(x=>x)` ?

Comment: I called`ToString` just to match with string id type, and my UserManager asks for a `string`. And at first it was without `OrderByDescending(x => x.UserID).Select(x => x)` but the value is the same.

Comment: I feel like you expect `OrderByDescending(x => x.UserID).Select(x => x)` to do something it is not capable of doing. Are you trying to get a `Single` user id?

Comment: Yea I am trying get a `single value` so I can search it in `UserManager` and get the profile of a User. `UserID value` is the value of current user that posts the Job. I just want to `select` that value where the row `x =>x.ID == Session["Value"]`. Sessions values are not messed up only `LINQ` is not selecting what I am asking and pass forward the `Session Value`. Maybe is a problem the `UserID` value is a `GUID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been awhile since I have used C#, but your LINQ statement seems to be getting a list of `Job` objects and doing `ToString` on the list. If `Job` has reference to the `UserId` associated with it, then the following LINQ statement should work:

```
var userId = context.Jobs
                  .SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID.ToString() == jobId)
                  .?Select(j => j.<accessorToUserId>) // Not sure what your schema is
                  .?ToString()
```

Notice the `?`. This is just in case `SingleOrDefault` returns null then the following method calls won't happen. If, for some reason, more than one `Job` uses that `jobId`, which is really bad practice, replace `SingleOrDefault` with `FirstOrDefault`.

Also, `Select` is supposed to be used to map from type `T` to type `U`. Doing `Select(x => x)` is pointless since you are simply doing `T -> T`.

Comment: Thanks for inspiration with Single thing, but I did it with another approach.  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015081/c-sharp-linq-how-to-retrieve-a-single-result](Found here). Your suggestion with `Single` made me search in the right places. I will make edit how I did It.

Comment: I think they are the same, but I'm glad I could help